# How do I check if master has been merged into current branch

Tags: git

I was trying to find out if my branch was up to date with the remote master branch without actually running `git pull`, and I read elsewhere that

```
git branch -r --no-merged | grep master
```

should tell you.

However, if I run that, I don't get the remote master in the output (I do however get it in the output from `--merged`).

So I tried doing a fetch (not a pull), and running it. At this point, it decides that in fact, the I do need a merge,

```
git branch -r --no-merged HEAD | grep master
```

gives

```
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master
```

but interestingly, if I do -a, the local master doesn't come out in the list. But it does come out in the `--merged` list.

I found out a way of working out if I need to do a fetch, but the way these are working is confusing me somewhat. and I'd like to know what I'm missing.

Is `git branch -r` not actually going to the remote repository? Or am I missing something to make it do so? Or is the sequence above what I actually need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All (normal) git commands except `fetch` and `pull` will only look at the local state. So they will only tell you stuff about the state of the remote when you last fetched. If you really want to know if you should pull, do a fetch first.

If for some reason you do not want to do a fetch (I can’t think of a good one), have a look at `git ls-remote`.

Comment: I would add that doing pull is the same than fetch + merge and for that rason you need fetch and not pull to be able to compare remote and local branches. I'd also add that with `git branch -r` you're not removing a repo but a branch

Comment: Thanks. I was already using ls-remote to check if the fetch had been done, as I was getting a headache with the behaviour of `git branch`. In any case this check needs to be very light weight. Thanks for the explanation

Comment: @iberbeu `git branch -r` doesn't remove anything

Comment: true. I was thinking of `git branch -d`